# Convert text to number format in Excel

Tags: excel, text, numbers, format

How can I convert text representations of numbers into Excel numbers, especially negative values? For example, the string "9,669.34" (without quotes) should become the number `9,669.34` and the string "2,553.57-" (again, without quotes) should become the number `(2,553.57)`.

When I used the formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")+0`, it worked well, but only for positive values. I received the result `#VALUE!` for all negative values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (2,553.57), you can use `VALUE`, such as `VALUE("(2,553.57)")`.

Excel doesn't seem to recognize 2,553.57- as a valid number when it is a string, so assuming you have a value of "2,553.57-" in A1, you would have to do a little more work:

<strike>=VALUE(IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="-","-"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")))</strike>

**EDIT**

```
=VALUE(IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="-","-"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""),A2))
```

From the Microsoft site:

- Text can be in any of the constant number, date, or time formats recognized 
     by Microsoft Excel. If text is not in one of these formats, VALUE returns the 
     #VALUE! error value.
- You do not generally need to use the VALUE function in a formula because Excel 
    automatically converts text to numbers as necessary. This function is provided 
    for compatibility with other spreadsheet programs.

More information can be found at Microsoft's website:  [Value Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/value-text-HP010062583.aspx)

Comment: The =VALUE(IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="-","-"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))) only takes the negative value & not the positive value. How can I apply a formula that can convert both positive & negative values ? I hv hundreds of row to manage.

Comment: ok, I found it. I can do with =VALUE(IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="-","-"&SUBSTITUTE(A21,"-",""),A2)) OR =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="-",VALUE("-"&LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)),VALUE(A2)). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a column of these text-based numbers, select the column and use Data ► Data Tools ► Text to Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish. The trailing negative signs will be used to determine the sign of the resulting number, spaces (leading and/or trailing) will be removed and you will be left with raw numbers that you can apply a currency or number format to.

If the column is originally formatted as *Text*, change it to *General* before applying the **Text to Columns** command.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Select the column. Copy. Paste Special with "Multiply" option.

Then, as above, you can select Currency or Number in the droplist, decimal places, etc.